# How to modify a mobius strip?

Tags: pgfplots

I have modified some mobius code by Jakes to produce another mobius strip. Could you please help to make it more like the second photo below in overall appearance?
[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,colormap={mygreen}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,0); rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,0)}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-70]
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    view={-10}{70}
]
\addplot3 [
    surf, shader=faceted interp,
    point meta=x,
    colormap name=mygreen,
    samples=120,
    samples y=8,
    z buffer=sort,
    domain=0:360,
    y domain=-.5:.5
] (
    {(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*cos(x)},
    {(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*sin(x)},
    {0.5*y*sin(x/2)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you really want it to look like that, you should use 3D rendering software which supports directional light sources because that's responsible for a lot of what you're seeing in terms of shading and shadows.

Comment: I have changed a dozen of possible parameters in the codes but the width of the strip is not reduced and the whole shape is not like the second photo attached. I mean I like the shape as in the second photo of the post and outline pictures as in http://paulbourke.net/geometry/mobius/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this good enough?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,colormap={mygreen}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,255)}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
    view={-30}{45}
]
\addplot3 [
    surf, shader=faceted interp,
    point meta=x,
    colormap name=mygreen,
    samples=100,
    samples y=2,
    z buffer=sort,
    domain=0:360,
    y domain=-1:1
] (
    {(10+y*cos(3*x/2)))*cos(x)},
    {(10+y*cos(3*x/2)))*sin(x)},
    {y*sin(3*x/2)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Replace `samples y=2` by `samples y=3`

[image]

Comment: How to make the lines black not gray?

Comment: @Thumbolt That is what I want next. More precisely I want to control color of every line. It should be possible because `mesh` does something similar.

Comment: It would be good for single color printing. I look forward to your codes.